# How to customize active admin comments feature in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I need to send an email whenever the admin add a comment to a user. 
I am using active admin 0.4.3

[image]

How can I get this event and send email.  When I post a comment, In my console I can see the following actions performed

```
Started POST "/admin/comments"
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/comments/182
Started GET "/admin/comments/182"
Started GET "/admin/accounts/227"
```

I dont know how to access these functions. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by adding this code into your config/initializers/...

```
module ActiveAdmin

  class Comment  < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_create :send_email

    def send_email
      AdminMailer.comment_created(self.id).deliver
    end

  end

end
```

Please mind that you have to write the AdminMailer and that we only pass the id because our mailer uses redis to send the mail asynchronous. If you don't have this you can pass the object.

I tried to overwrite the create action of the `Admin::CommentsController` in the same way but it didn't work. It would be much nicer to have this in the controller because sending an email is more a business of the controller than of the model. Any ideas how to do this?

...ok...commented on an [active admin issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1727) which adresses the same question and got some good answers...

Answer (score 0):

As this is controller logic the best is to put it in the controller.
You can take a look at https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2493#issuecomment-24892236

Basically, for modifying the Comment controller you have to do it after loading:

```
ActiveAdmin.after_load do
  ActiveAdmin.register ActiveAdmin::Comment, as: 'Comment' do
    controller do
      after_action :send_email, only: [:create]

      def send_email
        AdminMailer.comment_created(self.id).deliver
      end
    end
  end
end
```